Persist the Web3 Provider in Redux to use it across different parts of the application
Can anyone guide me on how to store a provider in Redux and make it persist, given that Redux doesn't allow storing non-serializable data. My use case involves using Web3Auth for Google login, which gives me a provider. I need to store that provider in Redux and use it across different pages of the web application.
I tried saving it in redux but it's not saving due to it's non serializable nature

Why do you need to store a provider object in Redux? Why can't you just provide it to the entire app? This smells like an XY Problem. What are you really trying to do here, what problem are you really trying to solve? Please [edit] to clarify and provide a [mcve] of any relevant code you are working with. I invite you to also take the [tour] and to review Help/How to Ask to learn additional tips to improve the quality of your posts.

It’s a common practice in React apps to store instances of shared classes in a React context and provide access to them through custom hooks. This approach allows components to easily share and access these instances. You can read more about it here: Passing data deeply with context.

Storing instances in Context doesn’t persist them after a page refresh. I found a solution:
For email/password or MetaMask logins, I retrieve the provider from the window object if it's lost after a refresh.
For Web3Auth Google login, I recreate the provider instance using useEffect, keeping the connection status intact, so the Google login pop-up won’t reappear unless the user logs out.
